# How do I properly references images in Jasmine test fixtures?

Tags: javascript, html, jasmine

I'm trying to test a function that dynamically loads an image into an html fixture.  I'm using loadFixtures and that seems to work because I've tested other aspects of the fixture and they pass.  However, when I inspect the Spec Runner with Dev Tools is shows that my image failed to load because it is not found, even though I know the path is correct.  Do the fixtures get loaded somewhere different so that it can't find my image?  Here's my simple test:

```
describe("popup", function () {
var data,
    description,
    hoverText,
    numTabs;

beforeEach(function () {
    data = {
        stateAttributes: {
            StateTab1: {
                'State Test 1': 'State Test 1',
                'State Test 2': 'State Test 2',
                'State Test 3': 'State Test 3'
            },
            StateTab2: {
                'State Test 4': 'State Test 4',
                'State Test 5': 'State Test 5',
                'State Test 6': 'State Test 6'
            }
        },
        countyAttributes: {
            CountyTab1: {
                'County Test 1{Test Hover Text}': 'County Test 1',
                'County Test 2{Test Hover Text}': 'County Test 2',
                'County Test 3{Test Hover Text}': 'County Test 3'
            },
            CountyTab2: {
                'County Test 4': 'County Test 4',
                'County Test 5': 'County Test 5',
                'County Test 6': 'County Test 6'
            }
        }
    };

    description = biosatApp.identify.description(data, true);
    loadFixtures('NewPopupDescription.html');
    setFixtures(description);
    numTabs = $(".popuptab").length;
    hoverText = $(":image");
    console.log(hoverText);
});

it("should have 2 tabs", function () {
    expect(numTabs).toEqual(2);
});
});
```

Comment: Where are the images being referenced?

Comment: The image is relative to the SpecRunner.html:  http://localhost:65363/resources/BioSatMap_Images/$file/esriGenericInformation.png.  The html string with the image gets built in description and added to the fixture with setFixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the images are stored relative to the SpecRunner.html not the fixture.  I had my image in the wrong place.  It is now correctly found.